# How to select from an incoming stream of random numbers X% of the time?

Tags: c, statistics, probability

I've this sampling problem.

I have a series of inputs tagged with a random generated id. I want to randomly sample X% of these inputs based on this randomly generated id.

I think, if I am ok with biased sampler, I can do:

```
(id % 100) < X
```

But if I don't want to introduce bias then what should I do?

Comment: I don't understand. If the `id` is truly random, then your method should not introduce bias. If you think the `id` is not random, then generate a random number between 0 and 99 and use that as your sample.

Comment: What is the range of the random ID?

Comment: If you want to select X% of the inputs, why do you need to pay any attention to the random generated ID in the data?  Why not simply generate a random `double` value (`rv`) between `[0.0 .. 1.0)` and choose the row if `rv < X`.  one possible PRNG for that is POSIX [`erand48()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/erand48.html) (which means you can have your own sequence of random values separately from any other sequence), or you could use `drand48()`, or you can use `double drand(void) { return rand() / ((double)RAND_MAX + 1); }`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a source of unbiased integer random numbers, you can simply remove any number that that will add a bias with the modulo number.

Assuming you use the standard random, which will return a number 0..RAND_MAX:

```
bool sample_pct(int x) {
   int max_id = RAND_MAX - RAND_MAX%100 ;
   while ( true ) {
       int id = random() ;
       if ( id >= max_id) continue ;
       return (id%100) < x ;
   } ;
}
```

If you have other source of random numbers,  (with different range) code need to be adjusted for the range of values.